# Standard C++ libraries headers on gnu gcc site

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, gnu

I want to browse the source code of gnu implementation of C++ standard libraries -- header files as well as the implementation. 
I have landed myself into:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/index.html

My first step was to look  header file at:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/a01376.html

My question is that as per my understanding the typedeffed string sth like:
typedef basic_string string; 
should have been present in string header, but I don't see one here.

Questions:
--in which file is the definition of string symbol?
--I see that string header file includes lot many headers and if the typedeffed sring symbol is defined in one of these internal headers, is there a search bar something on this site thru which I can reach to the definition of a symbol straightway. (in case someone has already browsed stuff from this site before)

Thanks,
Jagrati

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of libstdc++ is implemented using only headers, but some parts of the STL, like `std::basic_string`, have compiled implementations.

The declaration of template `std::basic_string` is located in `/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/bits/basic_string.h` (replace '4.4.4' with `g++ -dumpversion`) and the implementation is in `/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/bits/basic_string.tcc`. The actual `typedef` of `std::string`, `std::wstring`, etc. is in `.../bits/stringfwd.h`. If you needed to instantiate `std::basic_string` with other template parameters, for example, then you do something like:

```
#include <bits/basic_string.tcc>

template class std::basic_string<long>;
```

The way that libstdc++ implements sets and maps (header-only) is kind of interesting, but also very complex because it uses a custom red-black tree implementation (`_Rb_tree`).

The libstdc++ implementation of `std::vector` (also header-only) is more self-contained, so it's worth a glance in `/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/bits/stl_vector.h` to give you an idea of the internals of libstdc++. Another interesting file is `.../bits/stl_algo.h`, which contains the definitions of STL algorithms.

**Note:** On Windows with MinGW, you'll find the libstdc++ headers in `lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include\c++\bits` of your MinGW installation, replacing '4.4.0' with `g++ -dumpversion`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find what you need directly in `/usr/include/c++`: since the standard tag library is composed by templates, most of the code it's placed directly in header files.

Also I tried to read them once, but trust me: you don't want to do it. :) Seriously, it's a bit messy.

Answer (score 1):

A quick grep told me that `typedef basic_string<char> string` is in `bits/stringfwd.h`. I'm using `gcc 4.5.0`.