# Where can I find the header "string" in c++ (windows or Linux)

Tags: c++, header

If I need to go through the class declaration of the std::string class in c++, how do I find it?

I am using MinGW in windows.I was able to find the standard C header files, but not the c++ ones.

Comment: That depends on installation details. Have you tried a search? (in linux terminal: `find / -name "string" -type f`)

Comment: [Pass the `-M` option to the compiler](http://www.math-linux.com/rubrique36/FAQ-C/FAQ-C-gcc-g/gcc-g-find-where-a-header-file-is).

Comment: I don't think the standard mandates a specific place for std::string. Perhaps in your IDE, you can "go to declaration" when you're "over" a std::string in your source code.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your MinGW installation. If you used the original mingw-get version, you should have the following directories [(according to this article)](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/IncludePathHOWTO):

```
c:/mingw/include/c++/4.6.3
c:/mingw/include/c++/4.6.3/mingw32
c:/mingw/include/c++/4.6.3/backward
c:/mingw/include
c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.3/include
```

Note that your installation directory and gcc version might differ.

However, usually you're just interested in the C++ library, which can be found in

```
<MinGWRoot>\include\c++\<gcc-version>\
```

```
C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.2> dir -File | head    

    Directory: C:\MinGW\include\c++\4.8.2


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        17.11.2013     10:01       2518 algorithm
-a---        17.11.2013     10:01       9495 array
-a---        17.11.2013     10:01      34101 atomic
```

On a unix system, they are usually in

```
 /usr/local/include
 libdir/gcc/target/version/include
 /usr/target/include
 /usr/include
```

Answer (score 0):

*From a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171535/standard-c-libraries-headers-on-gnu-gcc-site/3171567#3171567):*

The declaration of template `std::basic_string` is located in `/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/bits/basic_string.h` (replace '4.4.4' with `g++ -dumpversion`) and the implementation is in `/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/bits/basic_string.tcc`. The actual `typedef` of `std::string`, `std::wstring`, etc. is in `.../bits/stringfwd.h`.

On Windows with MinGW, you'll find the libstdc++ headers in `lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include\c++\bits` of your MinGW installation, replacing '4.4.0' with `g++ -dumpversion`.